# How to write a generic function that can serialise/deserialize any record from a map-like structure?

Tags: haskell, generics

I've been struggling with this using every single Generics library available (EOT, SOP, Data/SYB, and GHC.Generics). I have half-written code samples with every library, which either don't compile, or throw runtime errors.

The core question is this:

```
type FieldName = String
type FieldValue = String
type MapType = [(String, String)] -- can be an actual HashMap as well, but doesn't really matter
data User = User {name :: String, email :: String}
data Post = User {title :: String, body :: String}

gFromMap :: MapType -> Maybe a
gToMap :: a -> MapType

-- the following should work
gFromMap [("name", "Saurabh"), ("email", "redacted@redacted.com")] :: User -- Just (User{..})
gFromMap [("title", "Will this work?"), ("body", "I hope it does!")] :: Post -- Just (Post{..})

gToMap User{name="Saurabh", email="redacted@redacted.com"} -- [("name", "Saurabh"), ("email", "redacted@redacted.com")]
gToMap Post{title="Will this work?", body="I hope it does!"} -- [("title", "Will this work?"), ("body", "I hope it does!)]
```

Here is my half-written, non-compiling code, using `Generics.EOT`:

```
import Generics.Eot
import Data.String.Conv
import Data.Text

newtype HStoreList = HStoreList [(Text, Text)] deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

lookupHStore :: HStoreList -> Text -> Maybe Text

class FromHStoreList meta eot where
  fromHStoreList :: meta -> HS.HStoreList -> eot

instance FromHStoreList Datatype (Either a Void) where
  fromHStoreList dtype@Datatype{constructors=[Constructor{fields=(Selectors fields)}]} h = Left $ fromHStoreList fields h
  fromHStoreList dtype@Datatype{constructors=[Constructor{fields=(NoSelectors _)}]} h = error $ "Target data type doesn't seem to have any record selectors, which is not supported: " ++ (show dtype)
  fromHStoreList dtype@Datatype{constructors=[Constructor{fields=(NoFields)}]} h = error $ "Target data type doesn't seem to have any fields, which is not supported: " ++ (show dtype)
  fromHStoreList dtype@Datatype{constructors=constr:_} h = error $ "Multiple constructors found, which is not supported: "  ++ (show $ constructors dtype)


instance FromHStoreList [String] () where
  fromHStoreList _ _ = ()

instance (FromHStoreList [String] xs) => FromHStoreList [String] (Maybe Text, xs) where
  fromHStoreList [] h = error "shouldn't happen"
  fromHStoreList (f:fs) h = (HS.lookupHStore h (toS f), fromHStoreList fs h)
```

This gives the following compilation error:

```
   185  99 error           error:
     • No instance for (FromHStoreList [String] a)
         arising from a use of ‘fromHStoreList’
     • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘fromHStoreList fields h’
       In the expression: Left $ fromHStoreList fields h
       In an equation for ‘fromHStoreList’:
           fromHStoreList
             dtype@(Datatype {constructors = [Constructor {fields = (Selectors fields)}]})
             h
             = Left $ fromHStoreList fields h (intero)
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It's likely that an existing tool, like aeson, does what you want to do.

Comment: Aeson doesn't really solve *everything* that I want to do with generic functions. Although, I agree that this particular example does seem like something that can be done with Aeson. One basic problem with Aeson is that its data structures represent what is possible with a JSON (nested key-value pairs, arrays, etc), and one might not want all of that.

Comment: There is no way to make `gFromMap` total. It will either produce an error or you must change the return type to e.g. `Maybe a`. If you want a total `gFromMap`, you will have to use a dependently typed language (faking it in Haskell here gives you nothing). This is probably the source of your runtime errors. (In any case, if you have code which almost works but produces errors, you should post that code instead of asking people to re-write it for you)

Comment: @user2407038 having a `Maybe a` is also fine. Changed the question, and also added the half-written deserialisation code in in EOT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution with [GHC.Generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) following the style of the [GHC.Generics tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics)

#### Prerequisites

To start with, we need a few prerequisites. `DefaultSignatures, DeriveGeneric, TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts` are normal requirements for `GHC.Generics`. This particular problem uses `MultiParamTypeClasses` for a trick to figure out which types can be reliably converted to dictionaries, as well as `FlexibleInstances` (which follows `FlexibleContexts` around) and `TypeSynonymInstances` (because I'm lazy and typed `String` a few places).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DefaultSignatures, TypeOperators, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, TypeSynonymInstances #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import GHC.Generics
```

To keep myself sane I added a class for things that can be serialized to strings. For your example we only need to support `String`s, but I suspect you will rapidly encounter `Bool`s or `Int`s.

Any time we're deserializing (which can usually fail) it's nice to keep track of errors, so we have some idea of why it failed.

```
class Serializable a where
    serialize :: a -> String
    deserialize :: String -> Either String a   

instance Serializable String where
    serialize = id
    deserialize = Right . id
```

#### Generic Class

The `GMapSerializable k` class represents the class of generic representations that can be converted to and from maps. Converting from maps can fail. The extra `k` parameter denotes the type of key required for serialization/deserialization to work, and the current key is explicitly passes to both methods.

```
class GMapSerializable k f where
    gFromMap :: k -> Map.Map String String -> Either String (f a)
    gToMap :: k -> f a -> Map.Map String String
```

Instances will either use a `String` key if they need to know where to read or write a field or will by polymorphic over all keys.

For convenience we also make a corresponding non-generic class. It uses `()` for the key to signify that no key data is provided yet.

```
class MapSerializable a where
    fromMap :: Map.Map String String -> Either String a
    toMap :: a -> Map.Map String String

    default fromMap :: (Generic a, GMapSerializable () (Rep a)) => Map.Map String String -> Either String a
    fromMap map = to <$> gFromMap () map

    default toMap :: (Generic a, GMapSerializable () (Rep a)) => a -> Map.Map String String
    toMap x = gToMap () (from x)
```

#### Generic Instances

On to the instances. We'll start with a good one, `K1 a`, a value of type `a` held somewhere in the representation. In order to convert a value to or from a dictionary we'll need to know what key it should be stored in or read from. The `GMapSerializable String` instance requires that it be passed a `String` key.

```
instance Serializable a => GMapSerializable String (K1 i a) where
    gFromMap key map = K1 <$> (lookupE key map >>= deserialize)
    gToMap key (K1 x) = Map.singleton key (serialize x)

lookupE :: (Ord k, Show k) => k -> Map.Map k v -> Either String v
lookupE k = maybe (Left $ "Key not found: " ++ show k) (Right) . Map.lookup k
```

These keys will be provided when we encounter a metadata node for a selector, `M1 S` and the metadata `c` contains the selector name. `fixProxy` is a hack to get a correctly typed proxy for `selName` out of the `Either String` error monad. Usually you pass to `selName` the whole `M1` node that you happen to have around (or are building).

```
instance (Selector c, GMapSerializable String f) => GMapSerializable k (M1 S 
c f) where
    gFromMap _ map = fixProxy $ \proxy -> M1 <$> gFromMap (selName proxy) map
    gToMap _ m@(M1 x) = gToMap (selName m) x

fixProxy :: (a -> f a) -> f a
fixProxy f = f undefined
```

The remaining metadata nodes, `M1 D` for datatypes and `M1 C` for constructors, don't care what kind of keys they deal with.

```
instance GMapSerializable k f => GMapSerializable k (M1 D c f) where
    gFromMap key map = M1 <$> gFromMap key map
    gToMap key (M1 x) = gToMap key x

instance GMapSerializable k f => GMapSerializable k (M1 C c f) where
    gFromMap key map = M1 <$> gFromMap key map
    gToMap key (M1 x) = gToMap key x
```

Dictionaries represent products of many values, indexed by keys. We can provide a `GMapSerializable` instance for products of two values, `f :*: g`. When converting to a dictionary it converts each part to a dictionary and takes the union of the dictionaries for each part. When converting from a dictionary it builds each part reading from the same dictionary and then combines the parts into the product.

```
instance (GMapSerializable k f, GMapSerializable k g) => GMapSerializable k (f :*: g) where
    gFromMap key map = (:*:) <$> gFromMap key map <*> gFromMap key map
    gToMap key (a :*: b) = Map.union (gToMap key a) (gToMap key b)
```

We can also provide an instance for the unit, `U1`. It doesn't need to read anything from a dictionary - there's only one possible value. It similarly doesn't need to write anything to a dictionary; the `empty` dictionary suffices.

```
instance GMapSerializable k U1 where
    gFromMap _ map = return U1
    gToMap _ U1 = Map.empty
```

We notably won't be providing instances for composition or for sums. Composition would result in nested keys, which a single dictionary can't represent. Sums would require tags for which branch of the sum is taken; again something a single dictionary can't represent.

#### Example

Your example compiles and runs, with minor differences because I used a `Map` instead of a list of key-value pairs.

The data types derive `Generic` instances, and are given `MapSerializable` instances with the `default` implementation.

```
data User = User {name :: String, email :: String}
  deriving (Generic, Show)
instance MapSerializable User

data Post = Post {title :: String, body :: String}
  deriving (Generic, Show)
instance MapSerializable Post

main = do
    print (fromMap . Map.fromList $ [("name", "Saurabh"), ("email", "redacted@redacted.com")] :: Either String User)
    print (fromMap . Map.fromList $ [("title", "Will this work?"), ("body", "I hope it does!")] :: Either String Post)

    print . Map.toList . toMap $ User{name="Saurabh", email="redacted@redacted.com"} -- [("name", "Saurabh"), ("email", "redacted@redacted.com")]
    print . Map.toList . toMap $ Post{title="Will this work?", body="I hope it does!"}

    print (fromMap . Map.fromList $ [("title", "Will this work?"), ("not-the-body", "I hope it doesn't!")] :: Either String Post)
```

[Running Example](http://rextester.com/VNE12754)

Comment: `deserialize :: String -> Either String a ` is required only for other data types like Int/Bool, etc, right? Otherwise there's no practical case why deserialisation of a String to a String would fail.

Comment: Exactly, that's why the `deserialize` implementation for `String` always succeeds; it's just `Right . id`, which I guess has the more canonical name `return`.

Comment: `class GMapSerializable k f where` , so `k` is the *type of key* , which is `String` in this example, but can be something else in the future? What is `f` the record-type being (de)serialised?

Comment: `k` is always either `String` - a `String` key is required, or it's polymorphic over all types, no specific key is required. By asking the compiler to instantiate it to `GMapSerializable ()` we check that there isn't a `K1` sitting outside of an `M1 S`. It can't be something else in the future, the type of keys being `String`s is coded into the signatures of `gFromMap` and `gToMap`.

Comment: thanks for posting this solution **and** following-up on the comments. Unfortunately, I have more follow-up questions. Can I go-ahed and ask, or is this too much already?

Comment: Yes, `f` is in-essence the record type being (de)serialized. GHC.Generics converts types `to` and `from` a generic representation that's either a unit `U1`, a value of type `a`, `K1 i a`, metadata wrapped around another representation `f`, `M1 i c f`, a product `f :*: g`, a sum `f :+: g`, or a composition `f :.: g`.

Comment: `gToMap _ m@(M1 x) = gToMap (selName m) x` is easier to understand than the corresponding `gFromMap` BUT, if `M1 x` has the ability to give us the selector name AND the corresponding value of that selector, can we define the entire function here itself, instead of depending upon the instance of `K1 i a` -- for argument sake?

Comment: This is where everything goes for a toss in my understanding -- `gFromMap _ map = fixProxy $ \proxy -> M1 <$> gFromMap (selName proxy) map` HOW exactly does this function know which key is being deserialised? It's not being passed to it!

Comment: I *think* I'm building an intuition of what's going on here. Can this be rewritten and simplified using `ScopedTypeVariables`? `gFromMap _ map = fixProxy $ \proxy -> M1 <$> gFromMap (selName proxy) map`

Comment: There's a pesky extra type argument to `M1` that scoped type variables don't capture, but it doesn't matter what it is so `ScopedTypeVariables` would do the job. It's roughly equivalent to `let m = M1 ... (selName m) ... in m`. It knows which key is being deserialized from the type. `M1 S c` is metadata for a selector, the metadata is available from the type `c`. Encountering the field `title` in `Post {title :: ...}` is the point at which we know that we're deserializing the data in the `"title"` key.